# Xwiki login with credentials and SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, openid-connect, xwiki

I using opened connect authenticator for SSO with Keycloak by following https://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/OpenID%20Connect/OpenID%20Connect%20Authenticator/OpenID%20Authentication%20with%20Keycloak/. SSO is working fine but the problem is that xwiki redirect to keycloak SSO page directly. I want some options on login page that user want to login with credentials or with opened connect authenticator.

How can I achieve this task?